# ASP Listview, ItemPlaceHolder problems

Tags: asp.net, listview

I've got a problem here with a div not being placed that way I'd like it to.

This is the ASP code I'm using:

```
<asp:ListView ID="categoriesListView" runat="server">

    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div class="main" runat="server"> 
            <div ID="itemPlaceholder" class="sub" runat="server">

            </div>
        </div> 
    </LayoutTemplate>

    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <div class="main" runat="server"> 
            <div class="sub" ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                No data was returned.
            </div>
        </div> 
    </EmptyDataTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image AlternateText='<%# Eval("CategoryName") %>' ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("CategoryImgUrl", "~/Images/{0}") %>' />
        <asp:Label ID="ProductNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CategoryName") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
```

I was expecting results like this:

```
<div class="main">
      <div class="sub">
            ...
      </div>
      <div class="sub">
            ...
      </div>
      <div class="sub">
            ...
      </div>
      ...
</div>
```

The result was one big div "main" containing everything, with no "sub" divs.

If I added the itemPlaceholder one level deeper, the same thing would happen, now with 1 "sub" div and everything pushed in there. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to look like this:

```
<LayoutTemplate>
    <div class="main" runat="server"> 
        <div ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">

        </div>
    </div> 
</LayoutTemplate>

<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <div class="main" runat="server"> 
        <div class="sub" ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
            No data was returned.
        </div>
    </div> 
</EmptyDataTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
  <div class="sub" >
    <asp:Image AlternateText='<%# Eval("CategoryName") %>' ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("CategoryImgUrl", "~/Images/{0}") %>' />
    <asp:Label ID="ProductNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CategoryName") %>' />
  </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```